# Network Error: React Native, Axios, Laravel - Authentication

Tags: laravel, react-native, axios

I am new to React Native and Axios, I am trying to build an Authentication System, my API (Created in Laravel) is working well in Postman, when I come to test the whole application and try to login, I am getting this error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'error.response.data')]
* src\AuthProvider.js:36:36 in axios.post.then._catch$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:13 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\react-native\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:24 in setImmediate$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:181:14 in _callImmediatesPass
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:441:30 in callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:387:6 in __callImmediates
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:135:6 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:134:4 in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in flushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I am using my Android phone for testing, here is may code:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000';

export const AuthContext = React.createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {

    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider 
            value={{
                user,
                setUser,
                error,
                setError,
                login: (email, password) => {
                    axios.post('/api/sanctum/token', {
                        email,
                        password,
                        device_name: 'mobile',
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        const userResponse = {
                            email: response.data.user.email,
                            token: response.data.token,
                        };
                        setUser(userResponse);
                        SecureStore.setItemAsync('user', JSON.stringify(userResponse));
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        // const key = Object.keys(error.response.data.errors)[0];
                        // setError(error.response.data.errors[key][0]);
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                },
                logout: () => {

                    axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${user.token}`;

                    axios.post('/api/logout')
                    .then(response => {
                        setUser(null);
                        SecureStore.deleteItemAsync('user');
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error.response);
                    });

                }
            }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an Android Device try to change localhost by http://10.0.2.2:8000, if you try to access your Laravel project with the phone browser you'll see that you will not be able to access to your default project welcome but by changing it you'll be able.

Answer (score 0):

Already solved.
I used `ngrok`.. It's generating a custom `url` to use for the Android device.